# How to handle OptimisticLockException in a Container managedTransaction?

Tags: hibernate, ejb, wildfly, ejb-3.0, wildfly-10

I use Hibernate with wildfly 10.0.1. And my transactions are Container managed Transaction.

I frequently get[1] **`OptimisticLockException`** when updating the entries.
How can I handle this exception in CMT?
Why my wildfly is not managing properly?
Do I need to add any application level logic?

[1]

```
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

**Persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="apidb-persistence-unit"
        transaction-type="JTA">

        <description>Forge Persistence Unit</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/lobDS</jta-data-source>     
   <class>xx.core.model.base.CRMEntity</class>
        <class>xx.model.base.Company</class>
..
 <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="ss_password" />

            <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.2" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="5" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="500" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="30000" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" /> 
                <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rathadb" /> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user" value="XX" /> 
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password" value="XX" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize" value="1000" />
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit" value="2048" />

            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined" value="true" />
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. How are you persisting your entities? Is your transaction datasource XA datasource? What's your setup like for persistence?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi use Hibernate session to persist entities. session.save(entity);  ,  session.merge(entity); etc.. I have provided my persistence.xml

Comment: And I get My session like  session = getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);

Comment: Create an XA Datasource and see if you get the error. CMT must propagate to the persistence layer so you need to have an XA datasource.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi You mean I need to change my persistence .xml?

Comment: Again, either use JPA `EntityManager` or Hibernate `Session`. Each have their own behaviours so don't try and extract Hibernate Session from JPA EntityManager.

Comment: No, change your Datasource in Wildfly.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi thanks will try